# Issues with rewriting PCL Library Hashing code to the new .NET Standard Library

Tags: c#, xamarin, hash, xamarin.forms, .net-standard

Basically, I need to rewrite the below methods which work in older PCL Library project, but not in a .NET Standard Library one.

```
    public static string GenerateSalt()
    {
        var buf = new byte[16];
        (new RNGCryptoServiceProvider()).GetBytes(buf);
        return Convert.ToBase64String(buf);
    }

    public static string GenerateHash(string password, string salt)
    {
        byte[] bytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(password);
        byte[] src = Convert.FromBase64String(salt);
        byte[] dst = new byte[src.Length + bytes.Length];

        System.Buffer.BlockCopy(src, 0, dst, 0, src.Length);
        System.Buffer.BlockCopy(bytes, 0, dst, src.Length, bytes.Length);
        HashAlgorithm algorithm = HashAlgorithm.Create("SHA1");
        byte[] inArray = algorithm.ComputeHash(dst);
        return Convert.ToBase64String(inArray);
    }
```

So far I have tried making progress with using `RandomNumberGenerator.Create()` and `RandomNumberGenerator.GetBytes()` methods without success.

I'm getting errors explaining that `RandomNumberGenerator` is an interface, therefore no instance can be created (which is understandable), but I guess there has to be a way (I'm not very experienced in .Net & C#).

Comment: Hi, which version of .NET Standard are you targeting?

Comment: @KostyaK Version 1.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to do something like that:

```
    public static string GenerateSalt()
    {
        var buf = new byte[16];
        RandomNumberGenerator.Create().GetBytes(buf);
        return Convert.ToBase64String(buf);
    }

    public static string GenerateHash(string password, string salt)
    {
        byte[] bytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(password); //TODO: consider removing it
        byte[] src = Convert.FromBase64String(salt);
        byte[] dst = new byte[src.Length + bytes.Length];

        System.Buffer.BlockCopy(src, 0, dst, 0, src.Length);
        System.Buffer.BlockCopy(bytes, 0, dst, src.Length, bytes.Length);

        var provider = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, src, 1000);
        byte[] inArray = provider.GetBytes(20/*bytes like in SHA-1*/);

        return Convert.ToBase64String(inArray);
    }
```

Or check other APIs available for 1.4 version [here](https://github.com/dotnet/standard/blob/master/docs/versions/netstandard1.4_ref.md)

Comment: Thank you. Can you please take a look at the firtst method and the line `(new RNGCryptoServiceProvider()).GetBytes(buf);` -- how do I deal with that? I guess it would work then, so I can accept your answer.

Comment: @developer10 Try this one. Test it thoroughly to see if it works for you, though.

Comment: I already managed to do it by myself. I will nevertheless accept your answer because of the second method. Thank you!

Comment: @developer10 Thank you too. :)

Comment: @developer10 Also, please note that I changed the provider to Rfc2898DeriveBytes in the last revision.